# Delete resource properties without deleting the entire resource

Tags: rest

We create resource R1 using `POST /v1/api/resource` API endpoint.
We provide payload when creating R1 resource. Here's how payload looks like

```
{
    resourceValues: {
         "CustomerName": "customer_name",
         "CustomerLocation" : "USA",
         ...
    },
    "ttl": "30d",
    "clientId": "id-12234",
}
```

R1 resource is created with all the resourceValues stored in our database. This is the response:

```
{
     resourceId: "resource-id-1234",
     resourceExpiry: "Some Date",
     resourceAccessLink: "link to the resource",
     resourceValues: { // same what customer has provided
     }
},
```

Now we want to give customer the ability to delete the resourceValues without deleting the resource. Customer cannot edit the resourceValues. What should be the correct RESTFul API based on industry standards.

We have come up with different APIs

1. PATCH `/v1/api/resource/<resourceId>` with `body = {resourceValues: {}}`
2. PUT `/v1/api/resource/<resourceId>/resourceValues`
3. POST `/v1/api/resource/<resourceId>/clearResourceValues`
4. POST `/v1/api/resource/<resourceId>/resourceValues/.clear`
5. DELETE `/v1/api/resource/<resourceId>/resourceValues`

Any other suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Either of these would be RESTful designs.

- PATCH /v1/api/resource/ with body = {resourceValues: {}}
- PUT /v1/api/resource/ with body = {resourceValues: {}}

Patch has a couple different ways to do it.  merge patch or json patch

This is a great explanation of the diff between PUT and the two types of PATCH

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#put-methods

[RFC5789-PATCH http method](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789)

Two flavors of PATCH

[JSON Merge Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7396)

[JSON Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902)

PUT expects the entire resource to be sent in the body while PATCH only expects the changes to be sent in the body.